# Bring a window to the front in Maemo

Tags: qt, maemo

I've got a Maemo (Qt) app that does some integration with the built-in media player via D-Bus. All the control functionality I need is complete, but I've got a requirement to show my application window (which gets backgrounded when playback starts) instead of the media player when the playback window is closed (it's a stacked window).

It should go like this: user clicks item in my Qt application, which launches the media file in the native media player. User watches media file, exits by clicking the arrow on the playback window. I'd like to somehow catch this event and bring my application to the front instead of showing the media player's main window.

Is it even possible on Maemo? I'm thinking that some low-level X coding might be required.

Answer (score 2):

Answer was painfully obvious, I can catch a state_changed signal from D-Bus- state=0 when the window is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `raise()` method of Qt windows.